Intersection of parabolas at $y = x$?
Intersection of parabolas at $y = x$?
CONJECTURE: if a given point $(x,y)$ such that $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ , generates two parabolas with the $x$ axis and with $y$ axes as directrix, than I hypothesize they intersect at least once, and this point will be at the line $y = x$.
This problem rose as I was going through Simmons' "Calculus and Analytic Geometry" chapter 1 problem 28 page 10:
Find every point whose distance from each of the two coordinate axes equals its distance from the point $(4, 2)$.
When I solved this problem, I thought about two parabolas intersecting to explore the point-line equidistance property, but solving the system ended up in a quartic, so I gave up this path and tried planar geometry instead.
 .
Havent been able to prove or disprove this. Any insights?
Thanks!
 .

seems worth persuing/ might try to do a specific problem or 2 ...

It seems a duplicate question:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3896578/find-every-point-whose-distance-from-each-of-the-two-coordinate-axes-equals-its

@ÁngelMarioGallegos not a duplicate, only  question as motivation. My question is the general case.

Hint: The distance between a point $P$ on a parabola and the focus is equal to the perpendicular distance of $P$ from the directrix. Suppose the two parabolas intersect at some point $Q$. What can be said about the perpendicular distance from $Q$ to both axes?
